# Frame leaves empty space when not displayed in PDF report

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I am using *iReport 4.5.1* to design the *JR* pdf report. I am using frame component  to group few fields in the report. And I am using "Print When Expression" option on the frame to display it only when a particular field is not null.

In the PDF reported generated, Frame and the data displays fine when the field is not null. But when it is null, frame is not displayed on the PDF but it is leaving a huge empty space. I am not able to figure a way to avoid this.

Please let me know if anyone already found a solution to it.

Here is piece from JRXML pasted below.

```xml
<frame>
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="11" y="90" width="544" height="120" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{facutlyMinimumTot} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <staticText>
        <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="544" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
        </reportElement>
        <textElement>
            <font fontName="Arial" size="16" isBold="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Time on Task]]></text>
    </staticText>
    <staticText>
        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="25" width="544" height="15"/>
        <textElement>
            <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Reading and Assignments]]></text>
    </staticText>
    <textField>
        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="40" width="544" height="15"/>
        <textElement/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Minimum Requirement: "+$F{facutlyMinimumTot}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
    <textField>
        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="55" width="544" height="15"/>
        <textElement/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["This Syllabus has "+ $F{facutlyAllActivityTot}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
    <staticText>
        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="75" width="544" height="15"/>
        <textElement>
            <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Participation and other course-work
    ]]></text>
    </staticText>
    <textField>
        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="90" width="544" height="15"/>
        <textElement/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Minimum Requirement: "+$F{studentMinimumTot}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
    <textField>
        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="105" width="544" height="15"/>
        <textElement/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["This Syllabus has " +$F{studentAllActivityTot}]]> </textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
</frame>
```

Answer (score 4):

Hidden elements leave blank space behind by default. To avoid this you should set the property `isRemoveLineWhenBlank` to true on the element, in this case the frame.

However, if there are other elements that share the same line and are visible, it will not be possible to collapse the space.